# When does a variable get its value assigned in c#?

Tags: c#, variables, runtime, compile-time

Example:

```
string input=Console.ReadLine();
Base obj1;
if (input=="a"){
    obj1=Derived();
else{
    obj1=Base();
    }
```

In this case i know that a variable gets its value at runtime. But what happens
when I just have `int x=5;`, when does x get its value, at runtime or compiletime?

Comment: It depends where it is.  If it's a local variable, for example, it does not exist until runtime, since that's when the stack frame is created.  Therefore there's no choice.  Having said that, of course, compiler optimization may avoid the need for a 'variable' at all; '5' may be used directly if 'x' is never other than 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (almost) always check with IL/JIT ASM.

For a simple class, for example:

```
public class C {
    public void M() {
        var x = 6;
    }
}
```

Both IL and JIT ASM are for Debug configuration, in release unused variables will be cutted away.

IL:

```
.method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 4 (0x4)
        .maxstack 1
        .locals init (
            [0] int32 x
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldc.i4.6 // Push 6 onto the stack as int32 (0x1C)
        IL_0002: stloc.0 // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0 (0x0A)
        IL_0003: ret
    } // end of method C::M
```

JIT ASM:

```
C.M()
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: sub esp, 8
    L0006: xor eax, eax
    L0008: mov [ebp-8], eax
    L000b: mov [ebp-4], ecx
    L000e: cmp dword ptr [0x18d0c190], 0
    L0015: je short L001c
    L0017: call 0x6b214e50
    L001c: nop
    L001d: mov dword ptr [ebp-8], 6
    L0024: nop
    L0025: mov esp, ebp
    L0027: pop ebp
    L0028: ret
```

So as you can see, value 6, for example, is compiled into IL code itself as is, but assignment to [x], which is in memory, happens in the runtime.

Site to play around: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgZgAIMiBhIgbzyNpONQBYiBZACgEoqa7eA3MACciADyIBeIgDYA3D1oBfPAqA=